# releasing the viewcontroller in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have a navigation based application and I see a leak in the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the app delegate. I am not sure where to release the `viewController`.

**Header file:**

```
@class ViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
ViewController *viewController;
  }
 @property (nonatomic, retain)  UIWindow *window;
 @property (nonatomic, retain)  ViewController *viewController;
 @end
```

**.m File**

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 


    UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    nvc.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    nvc.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [window addSubview:[nvc view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
- (void)dealloc {
     [viewController release];
     [window release];
     [super dealloc];
}
```

Adding the `[nvc release]` after the windows `addSubview` line makes my `viewcontroller` disappear .Adding `autorelease` to the `alloc` line freezes the app and cannot redirect to the next view. I would like to fix all leaks before I submit the app to the app store. Can anyone please tell me what is the correct place to release the `rootViewController`.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep the navigation controller in a @property of the app's delegate, instead of the viewcontroller. So this would work:

```
Header file:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

   UIWindow *window;
   UINavigationController *navController;
  }
  // if using current compiler, just omit these ivars above

 @property (nonatomic, retain)  UIWindow *window;
 @property (nonatomic, retain)  UINavigationController *navController;

 @end
```

Then @synthesize as usual and release the backing instance variable in your dealloc.

BTW, if you do not need to support iOS3, then don't add the nav controller's view as a subview, just set the window's rootviewcontroller instead.

So do this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

instead of:

```
[window addSubview:[nvc view]];
```

Then of course creating your navigation controller becomes:

```
self.navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController] autorelease];
[viewController release];
```

Assuming you just created 'viewcontroller' earlier (you didn't show that)

Answer (score 0):

i could be wrong but i believe that normally rootviewcontroller usually is like the delegate meaning its never released till the application is closed.  however to answer your question the proper place to release most things is in the dealloc method (just add it if its not there, it will be called)

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[varName release];
}
```

post saying simliar things as me:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5953-navigationcontroller-appdelegate-crash.html

couldnt find an official link but im pretty sure im right

Comment: please dont flame me, i understand even the word most is dangerous since there are plenty of times to release somewhere else.  im just saying the norm for people new to objective c and cocoa touch

Comment: I am releasing the viewController in the dealloc method. I want to release nvc (the navigationViewController) I am initializing in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: isnt your nav controller on your Main Window and setup in your delegate?  your questions specifically says "release  the rootviewcontroller" not the nvc.  but either way, where is your nvc declared (i see it in the code above but i dont know what file thats in)

Comment: Yes it is. I have set it up in the delegate. In the code for nvc, I have a menu with buttons etc.

Comment: well like i said in my post then, delegate and delegate members are never released, they stay open for the length of the program.  let me try to find a link to documentation that states as such

Comment: Ok. But I am still able to see the leak when I run the analyzer with the message "Potential leak of an object allocated on line 30 and stored into nvc". But I am releasing the viewController in the dealloc method :(.

Comment: post some more code than, i realize thats the line number from the stack trace but still, what is viewController and how is it allocated/created

Comment: The viewController is the rootViewController. Editing the post with more code.

Comment: where do you alloc and init your viewController to somthing?

Comment: errr comments getting to long.  normally viewController would be of type UIViewController and would be another class that you created (of type UIViewController of course).  also you dont addsubview with navigation controller your push or pop them